# Facebook Login with Spring Social using Existing User Access Token

Tags: ios, rest, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

**Here's what I currently have:**

- Spring REST service where many of the APIs require the user to be authenticated
- A 'registration' API (/api/v1/register)
- A 'login' API that takes username/password (/api/v1/login)
- 'Facebook Login' API that relies on Spring Social and Spring Security to create a User Connection and log my user in (/auth/facebook)

My problem is that I want these APIs to be used by multiple clients, but the way Facebook Login is right now, it doesn't work well on mobile (works great on a website).

**Here's the mobile scenario:**

- I use Facebook's iOS SDK to request permission from the user
- Facebook returns a user access token
- ***I want to send my backend service this token and have Spring Social accept it, create the User Connection, etc.***

Can this be done? Or am I going to have to write my own API to persist the User Connection?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same issue and here's how I made it work. You probably have a SocialConfigurer somewhere with the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public FacebookConnectionFactory facebookConnectionFactory() {
        FacebookConnectionFactory facebookConnectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory("AppID", "AppSecret");
        facebookConnectionFactory.setScope("email");
        return facebookConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(facebookConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
    }

    // Other @Bean maybe ...
}
```

From here, what you can do is, in a Controller/RestController, add a mapping with a RequestParam for your token that you will send to your server:

```
@Autowired
private FacebookConnectionFactory facebookConnectionFactory;

@Autowired
private UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/my-facebook-url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String fb(@RequestParam String token) {
    AccessGrant accessGrant = new AccessGrant(token);
    Connection<Facebook> connection = facebookConnectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);

    UserProfile userProfile = connection.fetchUserProfile();
    usersConnectionRepository.createConnectionRepository(userProfile.getEmail()).addConnection(connection);

    // ...

    return "Done";
}
```

**Useful references**

- [UsersConnectionRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/social/connect/UsersConnectionRepository.html)
- [ConnectionRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/social/connect/ConnectionRepository.html)

Comment: Hi @Philippe! Have you this working with spring-social-facebook version 2? Thanks

Comment: @troig, precisely yes. I also have spring-social-core/web/config/security:1.1.2 are you having any issues with it?

Comment: Thanks again @Philippe! It worked upgrading spring-social-core version to 1.1.2 as you say. There is a bug with my previous version (1.1.0). +1

Comment: Hi Philippe. Unfortunately I cannot accept it because I didn't make the question. Maybe @AlexG could considerate it. Thsnks again, in my case it worked pretty well

Comment: You can use FacebookTokenAuthenticationFilter which extends SocialAuthenticationFilter of Spring Social Security API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911723/spring-social-authentication-filter-for-stateless-rest-endpoints-which-use-faceb